# How to find out what exactly is causing a NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

So I'm making an application, and everything is running great, until the following happens:

[image: NullReferenceException]

I have checked through the debugger but I can't find exactly what is causing this exception. I have a feeling that the root cause is on the SQL side of things, as that is the only part that I have changed recently, but I need to know exactly where the `NullReferenceException` is in order to know what SQL code to fix.

Here is a stack trace, if that helps (I don't expect you guys to know exactly what is causing the `NullReferenceException`, I just can't seem to find it and I'm completely lost):

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPRow.CopyContent(PdfPRow copy) +124
   iTextSharp.text.pdf.ColumnText.GoComposite(Boolean simulate) +8178
   iTextSharp.text.pdf.ColumnText.Go(Boolean simulate) +203
   iTextSharp.text.pdf.ColumnText.Go() +33
   iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDocument.AddPTable(PdfPTable ptable) +426
   iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDocument.Add(IElement element) +7594
   iTextSharp.text.Document.Add(IElement element) +394
   BigYOperationsConsole.Helpers.PdfHelper.ChecklistPdfStream(Checklist cl) in C:\workspace\BigYOperationsConsole\Helpers\PdfHelper.cs:129
   BigYOperationsConsole.Controllers.ChecklistsController.ExportPDF(Int32 id) in C:\workspace\BigYOperationsConsole\Controllers\ChecklistsController.cs:776
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +150
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +409
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +127
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +436
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +61
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +305
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +830
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +232
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +68
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +141
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +61
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +110
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +690
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +194
```

**Update:** This appears to be a bug with colspans in iTextSharp 5.0.6. I upgraded to 5.1.1 and everything appears to be working just fine now. See my comments below for more details. The strange part is that everything was working with 5.0.6 ...

Comment: If it were coming from SQL code, you'd be getting some kind of SQL exception.

Comment: You use the iTextSharp component, which is open source. You could use the source instead of precompiled dlls and debug through it, maybe the bug is not in your code.

Comment: I picked up iTextSharp from NuGet (NuGet official package source). Is there an option in NuGet to get the source code or do I have to get that somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do the following:

First, adjust the VS as described below:

1)  Go to the Debug-->Exceptions dialog and check the Common Language Runtime Exceptions and check the checkbox in the Thrown column;

2)  Go to the Tools-->Options-->Debugging and uncheck the Enable Just My Code (Managed Only) checkbox.

Now run the project and try to reproduce this issue.  The setting above should force the debugger to stop at the method where the exception is thrown.  If you do not own the source of this library, use Reflector to analyze the code of this method.  Hope, this helps.

Comment: Ok, I downloaded the source code for iTextSharp and ran through the debugger. This exception is only happening when I have a cell with a colspan greater than one. What is happening is the row will only have one cell with a colspan propery, and all the other cells are null. I will probably open a new question for that as it isn't within the scope of this question. The strange part is that this code was working until just recently...

Comment: Update: no question necessary. I just upgraded the library from 5.0.6 to 5.1 and everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

The `doc` variable is null when you attempt to call the `.add` method. Need to see the rest of them method or more code to figure out why.

Comment: The call stack suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

NullReferenceException is thrown when you try to access an object member when the object itself is null.  Is the `doc` variable set to an instance of an object or is it null?  It's also possible that either 1) checklistTable is null or 2) one of the reference-type members of checklistTable is null.  If either are true and code within the .Add() method of the doc object is trying reference such a member, you'll get that exception.

Another good debugging tip is to go to Windows > Debug > Stack Trace.  When you hit the exception, you can actually follow the call stack backwards and look at the scope of each call to see what's null.

**Edit** Okay, so checklistTable couldn't be null or you'd get an exception earlier (I didn't look at your code good enough).  However, one of its members could still be null and, if one of that member's members is being referenced in the .Add() method, you'll get that exception.